# Why doesn't sudo -S work for 'mysql' command?

Tags: sudo

I generally run `sudo mysql database < database.dump` and type the password on prompt.

In order to automate this, I tried to execute `echo 'password' | sudo -S mysql database < database.dump` but it is not recognizing my password.

I have also tried without success:

```
mysql_cmd="mysql database < database.dump"
echo 'password' | sudo -S $mysql_cmd
```

I can `sudo -S` other commands normally. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The file `database.dump` is being read in on standard input. `sudo -S` reads
the password, followed by a newline, from standard input. You may be able to
use this instead:

```
( echo 'password'; cat database.dump ) | sudo -S mysql database
```